# How to set the value of the SelectedItem property in devexpress combobox BarItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, devexpress

It is example Combobox in which everything is working good and selected value varies depending on changes CurrentPlanSet.

```
       <dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding PlanSets, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                               DisplayMember="Name" 
                               ValueMember="Name"
                               SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPlanSet, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               />
```

In this example the selected value does not change depending on CurrentPlanSet changes.

```
<dxb:BarEditItem Content="Plan Sets" EditWidth="350">
                <dxb:BarEditItem.EditStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxe:ComboBoxEdit}">
                        <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="{Binding     CurrentPlanSet, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Style>
                </dxb:BarEditItem.EditStyle>
                <dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings  >
                    <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings ItemsSource="{Binding PlanSets, Mode=TwoWay}" ValueMember="Id" DisplayMember="Name" />
                </dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
            </dxb:BarEditItem>
```

How to correctly set the value of the SelectedItem property in second code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectedIndex is not the same as SelectedItem.
This is the same as with the default WPF Controls.

SelectedIndex is the Index of the CollectionItem, you have selected/set selected (Integer). The SelectedItem is the Item Object itself.

**Example:**
Lets take this Collection: `new ObservableCollection<string>(){ "String1", "String2", String3"}`
If the SelectedItem is/should be String1 the SelectedIndex is 0.

So just replace

```
<Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="{Binding CurrentPlanSet, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

with

```
<Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding CurrentPlanSet, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```